# Can't install/start mysql server

Tags: mysql, debian

I can't install mysql server 5.5 on Debian system.
Getting this error. I tried 5 times but same problem :(
I'm also in superuser 
[image: ErrorImage]

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

`apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`

and got the error after password setup wizard for root user.

Please help

Comment: I think you forgot to post the error message you're getting.

Comment: You might have to type sudo before your commands

Comment: http://imgur.com/vClA6sy

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message in plain text in your question. It will make it easier for us to help you that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get purge mysql*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

If this is not be helpful, you can try install mysql from MySQL Repository, but you must remember - in this moment server have stable version: 5.7.x!